# Vertically middle placement in Beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Members}
\begin{columns}[T] 
\hfill
\begin{column}{.32\textwidth}
\hspace{2mm} \includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{john.jpg} \hspace{2mm} John\\
\hspace{2mm} \includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{jane.jpg} \hspace{2mm} Jane\\
\end{column}
\hfill
\begin{column}{.32\textwidth}
Middle Part
\end{column}
\hfill
\begin{column}{.32\textwidth}
Right Part
\end{column}
\hfill
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The images are toward the top of the frame. How can I place them in the (vertical) middle? I know that for horizontal middle, I can use \centering or \begin{center}, but for vertical I have no idea.

Comment: `beamer` palces frame content vertically centered by default. If you uses `t` class or frame option, the contents is top aligned. Your code uses default style and all contents is vertically centered in my computer. So, I don't understand your question.

Comment: If your problem has been solved, write down the solution, mark a solution or write down what else you did. This information might be useful for other users.

Comment: @Ignasi You're right. I copied the code from somewhere else and it has the [T]. Silly me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I packaged the text next to the pictures into parboxes. In general, I recommend not to use fixed space.

```
\begin{column}{.32\textwidth}
\hspace*{2mm} \includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{test1} 
\parbox[c][0.2\textheight][t]{\linewidth}{
\hspace*{2mm} John}\\
\hspace*{2mm} \includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{test1} 
\parbox[c][0.2\textheight][t]{\linewidth}{
\hspace*{2mm} Jane}\\
\end{column}
```

Note, that the parbox has currently overwidth, because it is `\linewidth`, but not aligned left, since there is the picture in between.

[image: I hope, this is what you want]